# C# is the Main problem

Tags: restricted-source, programming-puzzle, c#

This programming puzzle is inspired by another question which has been asked here yesterday but which was deleted by the author...

**The challenge:**

Create an executable binary (Windows .EXE or Linux binary) using Visual C# (or your favorite C# IDE) which prints the following text to the standard output:

```
Main() is the main method of C# programs!
```

... without using the 4 consecutive letters M-A-I-N appearing in any source file!

Notes:

- If your source code contains the text `remainder` (for example) it contains the 4 consecutive letters M-A-I-N, however if it contains `mxain` the 4 letters would not be consecutive any more so `mxain` would be allowed.
- You are not allowed to run any programs but the C# IDE nor change the settings of the C# IDE to run other programs (but the ones it would normally run such as the C# compiler).

  Otherwise you could simply say: "I write a Pascal program using the C# IDE and invoke the Pascal compiler in the 'pre-build' steps of my C# project".

  This would be too simple.
- Users of an IDE that can be extending using "plug-ins" (or similar) or that have built-in binary file editors (hex-editors) would have a **too** large advantage over users of other C# IDEs.

  Therefore these featrues should also not be used.
- Using the other non-ASCII-Editors (such as the dialog window editor) is explicitly allowed!
- The user asking the original question proposed using the backslash in function names just like this: `static void M\u0061in()` Because this answer has already been read by other users it will not be accepted any more!
- A user asked if it would be allowed to simply type in an .EXE file into the source code editor and to save the file as ".exe" instead of ".cs". Answer: I doub't that this is possible because both valid Windows and Linux binaries contain NUL bytes. However if you find a valid binary that can be created this way you have a valid solution.

The name of this site is "Programming Puzzles **&** Code Golf" - this is a "Programming Puzzle", not "Code Golf": The challenge is to find a working solution before all other users, not to find a solution shorter than all other solutions.

Therefore the **first post describing a working solution wins**!

Good luck!

By the way: I have a solution working under Visual C# Express 2010.

Comment: What stops me from using my C# IDE as a text (or binary) editor to directly type out an executable?

Comment: Which answer wins the challenge? The first valid answer? You should specify the winning condition

Comment: If the IDE contains some hexadecimal editor or similar this would NOT be allowed. If you manage to use the ASCII text editor to type in a valid binary file this would be allowed. Note that a valid binary file contains bytes in the range 0x00 to 0x1F!

Comment: @MartinRosenau Then you are disallowing newlines

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg 1) Why did you delete your answer? It was not my solution but it was correct! 2) Why disallowing newlines?

Comment: @MartinRosenau It was not deleted by me, others deleted it

Comment: I think this is overall an interesting challenge. "Write a C# program without main". However, most of the rules are about which tools/IDEs to use and banning certain approaches. I'd love to see more programming puzzles, (as opposed to code-golf) but this one is underspecified. I'd recommend using [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I voted to delete the answer, as it was explicitly against your rules.

Comment: @TimmyD As far as I remember TùxCräftîñg was one of the users discussing about the question yesterday and not the user asking it. Was I wrong?

Comment: @MartinRosenau `\n` is codepoint 0xA

Comment: ...Consider the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## C# Interactive Window

Open the C# Interactive Window (View > Other Windows > C# Interactive in Visual Studio 2015). I suppose not all IDEs will have this.

This approach executes C# in the Interactive Window in order to create a C# exe that prints the desired string without the author ever writing `main`. As a bonus, the exe's IL also does not contain `main`.

Run the following code in the Interactive Window

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
var appMeow = (dynamic)System.Type.GetType("System.AppDom" + "ain").GetProperty("CurrentDom" + "ain", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null);
var asmName = new AssemblyName("MEOW");
var asmBuilder = appMeow.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var module = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MEOW", "MEOW.exe");
var typeBuilder = module.DefineType("Meow", TypeAttributes.Public);
var entryPoint = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("EntryPoint", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public);
var il = entryPoint.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Meow() is the meow method of C# programs!");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "eow");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "ain");
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(string).GetMethod("Replace", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }), null);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("Write", new[] { typeof(string) }), null);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
asmBuilder.SetEntryPoint(type.GetMethods()[0]);
asmBuilder.Save("MEOW.exe");
```

Use `Environmnent.CurrentDirectory` to see where the exe was created. Run it to observe the desired output.

[image]

Resulting IL:
[image]

Comment: I actually like this one better, then the WPF one, because you actually have no Main() in your Assembly whatsoever.

Comment: Your solution is interesting. It is the second one so you will win if the users should convince me that the first post is not a valid solution (for what reason ever).

Comment: If you ask me it doesn't really matter which post wins, since they are both by the same user.

Comment: @hstde - Sorry, I did not see this. Thanks.

Comment: @milk You posted two valid solutions (well, some users have doubt about the first one) so you win. Congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

## WPF Application

1. Create a new WPF application.
   [image]
2. Replace all instances of `Main` with `Meow`
   [image]
3. Rename `MainWindow.xaml` to `MeowWindow.xaml`. This will automatically rename `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to `MeowWindow.xaml.cs`.

[image]

4. In project properties, change the Output type to `Console Application` so the console is created.
   [image]
5. Add console write for the desired output string in your `MeowWindow` constructor
   [image]
6. Ctrl+Shift+F to confirm there's no `main` anywhere in the source directory.
   [image]
7. F5 / compile and run.
   [image]

#### How it works

For WPF applications, Visual Studio generates `obj\Debug\App.g.cs` which contains the `Main` method. The generated `Main` creates an instance of your WPF app and starts it.

Comment: Interesting solution. **Anyone who thinks that this is not a valid solution?** If anyone thinks that this post is not valid please post a comment. Otherwise I will declare this solution the winning one because it was obviously the first one posted.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I feel that since you could decompile the wpf app and there would be a main method that this is invalid, more strongly because the same user posted another answer that does not have this ambiguity

Comment: I just saw that both answers were posted by the same user. In this case this user will win anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Just as a reference

My idea was similar to "milk"'s second idea:

Find a way to let the IDE execute code and write an executable to the disk.

I explicitly mentioned Windows and Linux binaries because I thought about writing the binary .EXE file using `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` so it would not neccessarily be a .NET EXE file.

My problem was that VS Express 2010 seems not to have an interactive console so I had to find a replacement for that - I found the following:

Create a DLL project with a dialog window and a custom control; compile the project and add the custom control to the dialog window. The dialog window editor will then call the code of the custom control - and in this code you may write the .EXE file to the disk...

Answer (score -5):

I had to break the rules because I used vim with csc...

```
class C {
    static void \u004d\u0061\u0069\u006e(){
        Syste\u006d.Co\u006esole.Write("\u004d\u0061\u0069\u006e() is the \u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e \u006dethod of C# progra\u006ds!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the downvotes?

Comment: Surely this would contain "Main" in the binary?

Comment: Maybe because you directly stated that you broke the rules.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem It was mainly to show this rule was simply stupid >_>